# How can I use the row.names attribute to order the rows of my dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, random-forest

I created a random forest and predicted the classes of my test set, which are living happily in a dataframe:

```
row.names   class  
564028      1
275747      1
601137      0
922930      1
481988      1
...
```

The  `row.names` attribute tells me which row is which, before I did various operations that scrambled the order of the rows during the process.  So far so good.

Now I would like get a general feel for the accuracy of my predictions.  To do this, I need to take this dataframe and reorder it in ascending order according to the `row.names` attribute.  This way, I can compare the observations, row-wise, to the labels, which I already know.

Forgive me for asking such a basic question, but for the life of me, I can't find a good source of information regarding how to do such a trivial task.

The documentation implores me to:

> use `attr(x, "row.names")` if you need to retrieve an integer-valued set of row names.

but this leaves me with nothing but `NULL`.

My question is, how can I use `row.names` which has been loyally following me around in the various incarnations of dataframes throughout my workflow?  Isn't this what it is there for?

Comment: There is a subtlety to this question in that there is a column named 'row.names' which is NOT the same as the attribute named 'row.names'. The downvote I just got (18 months after my reply) might or might not be appropriate. I suppose other readers can throw in their opinions.

Comment: Yes, it's not really clear, as the text does specifically say "according to the row.names _attribute_", and the accepted answer operates on the `row.names` attribute. In which case, I think @ToNoY's answer is the right one. (It worked correctly for me.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
new_df <- df[ order(row.names(df)), ]
```

Comment: People looking for the same thing, check out ToNoY's answer below. It will save you time when you find out it orders it wrong

Answer (score 37):

None of the other solutions would actually work.

It should be:

```
# Assuming the data frame is called df
df[ order(as.numeric(row.names(df))), ]
```

because the row name in R is `character`, when the `as.numeric` part is missing it, it will arrange the data as `1`, `10`, `11`, ... and so on.

Comment: It does not seem to produce a better ordering with `as.numeric`

Answer (score 7):

If you have only one column in your dataframe like in my case you have to add drop=F:

```
df[ order(rownames(df)) , ,drop=F]
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness:

@BondedDust's answer works perfectly for the rownames attribute, but your example does not use the rownames attribute. The output provided in your question indicates use of a column named "row.names", which isn't the same thing (all listed in @BondedDust's comment). *Here* would be the answer if you wished to sort by the "row.names" column in example given in your question (there is another posting on this, located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r?rq=1)). This answer assumes you are using a dataframe named "df", with one column named "row.names":

```
ordered.df <- df[order(df$row.names),]   #this orders the df by the "row.names" column
```

Alternatively, to order by the first column (same thing if you're still using your example):

```
ordered.df <- df[order(df[,1]),]         #this orders the df by the first column
```

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This will be done almost automatically since the "[" function will display in lexical order of any vector that can be matched to rownames():

```
df[ rownames(df) , ]
```

You might have thought it would be necessary to use:

```
df[ order(rownames(df)) , ]
```

But that would have given you an ordering of 1:100 of 1,10,100, 12,13, ...,2,20,21, ... , because the argument to "[" gets coerced to character.

Comment: Two issues: First, I believe the function for data frames is `row.names` (although `rownames` does seem to work, probably to save everyone's sanity). Second, I just tried your suggestion and, without the `order` part, the rows were simply spit out in the order they are already in — no reordering took place. @ToNoY's tip to convert to numeric worked for me, though.

Comment: `rownames` work with any object of 2 or more dimensions. Furthermore, the  example above is confusing since the `row.names` attribute never is labeled by the print function on the same row as column names. Agree that @ToNoY's answer is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame is named 'df'you can create a new ordered data frame 'ord.df' that will contain the row names of df as well as it values in the following one line of code:

```
>ord.df<-cbind(rownames(df)[order(rownames(df))], df[order(rownames(df)),])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_df <- df[ order(row.names(df)), ]
```

or something similar won't work. After this statement, the `new_df` does not have a rowname any more. I guess a better solution is to add a column as rowname, sort by it, and set it as the rowname

Comment: >df$rownames <- rownames(df)
 >df <- df[order(df$rownames), ]
 > #now delete the column
 >df$rownames <- NULL

Answer (score 0):

you can simply sort your df by using this :

```
df <- df[sort(rownames(df)),]
```

and then do what you want !